# Question regarding a wording of an exercise related to Noetherian topological space

Tags: general-topology

The exercise states "If $X$ is a Noetherian topological space, show that the union of 
any subset of the connected components of $X$ is always open and closed in $X$."

Does the question mean "If I have some connected components of $X$, then union of those will be open and closed"?
or does it mean "If I have some connected components of $X$, take any subset from each component and then the union of those will be open and closed"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mean "If you have some connected components of $X$, then union of those will be open and closed".
And the question is to show it is  closed, because any union of opens  subsets  is open.